# Calculate a score across columns and keep top-3 rows

Tags: r

I have to find 3 to 5 hottest days in a R dataset that goes for a few months.

The dataset is called AAA and I have column 1 the TIMESTAMP with the dates and column 3 the TAir_Avg took every minute.

Once I do this step, I have to find the hottest leaf temperatures off the 10 columns (thermocouples) that we have installed. HELP!

Tried this. I am using lubridate package, but I don't even know how it works.

```
AAA[,"DoY"] <- format.Date(AAA[,"TIMESTAMP"], format="%j") 

MaxTemps <- aggregate(AAA[,"TAir_Avg"], by=list(AAA[,"DoY"]), FUN=max)
```

Comment: What does `AAA[['DoY']]` look like? I'm assuming `AAA` is a data frame? Please produce a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to help us help you.